# What are/were the missing badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

There's a page for each individual badge (eg. [The Teacher Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1)), which shows the description & the list of people who recently earned it. Given that the URL is based off the badge's Id, why are there some badges that appear not to exist (eg. [16](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/16) and [29](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/29))? Were they removed? Have they not been discovered yet?

Comment: Cool question...

Comment: I think one of them was the hacker badge.

Answer (score 8):

I'll give you a hint.  So far, 16 and 29 are the only missing numbers in the sequence.  29 is a badge (secret) and 16 is just a gap in the identity field for that table, which as gnovice points out was the number for the original "Specialist" badge.

Answer (score 7):

Number 16 was the original "Specialist" badge. It existed at one point as evidenced by [the revision list for the SO badge FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/135648/list) (revision #8), but it was not "turned on" since they hadn't decided on the requirements for it yet. Once they made tag-specific specialist badges, it disappeared. Maybe there's still a place-holder for it?

Comment: Good find! So I guess that's it for the 'missing' badges...

Comment: I'm still wondering if 29 is another old one that fell by the wayside or a secret new one they haven't revealed yet...

Comment: It's highly likely that it's the "Hacker" badge. Jeff's been promising to issue it since the private beta. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/no-we-have-not-forgotten-about-the-hacker-badge/

Comment: Ahhhhh... I must have missed that blog post.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe they are the super-secret badges you have to earn before you know what they are?`</theory></conspiracy>`

SO's robots.txt disables caching on `/badges` so archive.org doesn't shed any light on what the pages once were. I would guess they are badges that were created, decided to be a bad idea and deleted

Comment: Nice detective work re: robots.txt/archive.org... I generally agree with your latter conclusion, although I'm secretly hoping for the former to be true. :)